# Assigning and Removing Permission Set via Apex

Tags: trigger, future, permission-sets

I'm trying to use apex to assign and remove a permission set in a trigger, but I keep running into issues. Here's my code:

```
public class PermissionSetAssignment_Handler{
@future
  public static void AssignPermissionSet() {
      string userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
      string permSetId = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Label = 'New Permission Set' LIMIT 1].Id; 
      If (permSetId !=null){
          List <PermissionSetAssignment> permSetCheck = [SELECT Id from PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSetId = : permSetId
                                                    AND AssigneeId = : userId];
          If (permSetCheck.size()==0){
                PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment
                    (PermissionSetId = permSetId, AssigneeId = userId);
                insert psa;
            }
      }

  }

 @future   
    public static void RemovePermissionSet(){
      string userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
      string permSetId = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Label = 'New Permission Set' LIMIT 1].Id;
        If (permSetId != null){
            delete [SELECT Id from PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSetId = : permSetId AND AssigneeId = : userId];

        }
      }

}
```

In my Trigger, I call the class at the beginning and end of the After Update portion.

```
if(trigger.isAfter){
        if (system.isBatch()== false){
            PermissionSetAssignment_Handler.AssignPermissionSet();
        }
// other stuff happens, call other classes to perform actions...
// once the actions are done, call the class to remove the permission set
        if (system.isBatch()== false){
            PermissionSetAssignment_Handler.RemovePermissionSet();
        }
```

I have been getting differing errors, like DELETE_FAILED, delete failed for this entity, future method can't be invoked, or DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found. I thought I was doing enough checking to see if the record already existed, but clearly I'm missing some steps.

Answer (score 4):

Your checks definitely are not robust enough. First, you need to be a lot more explicit about the future methods:

```
    if (!system.isBatch() && !system.isfuture() && !system.isqueueable() && !system.isScheduled()) {
```

Secondly, this can cause a query exception:

```
  string permSetId = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Label = 'New Permission Set' LIMIT 1].Id;
```

The exception would be "no rows for assignment". Instead, query for a list, and use the first result:

```
PermissionSet[] perms = [SELECT ...];
if(perms.size() == 1) {
```

Third, you can use `Database.insert(psa, false);` to ignore the duplicate value error.

For delete errors, make sure you use "without sharing":

```
public without sharing class PermissionSetAssignment_Handler{
```

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox, that definitely makes sense. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your fundamental need here.  Apex runs in the system context, so you should not need to set permission set assignments in triggers. See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm)

> Apex generally runs in system context; that is, the current user's
>   permissions ...  aren’t taken into account during code execution

If sharing rules are preventing access for code operations, than you need to look at `without sharing` keyword as sfdcfox mentions.

And even if you needed to assign a permission set for a specific set of actions in a trigger, it wouldn't work because the asynch execution means that the permission set will be assigned **after** the trigger's execution is complete, so the user wouldn't have those permissions while the trigger is executing anyway.

Comment: David Cheng we need to be able to assign the Permission Set using Apex so that we can utilize the Custom Permission, which we reference in Validation Rules. Would it make more sense to run them in the handler instead of the trigger?

Comment: No, because future methods aren't executed until all the synchronous operations in the transaction are complete.  See [discussion here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71055/can-future-execution-start-before-the-synchronous-execution-is-completed)